# Create N new dictionaries based on N keys from an original dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am new at python and here. I need to create N new dictionaries based on N keys from an original dictionary. 
Lets say I have an `OriginalDict {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6}` I need to create 6 new dictionaries having as keys (new keys are same) the value of the original. Something like that:

```
Dict1 {Name:a,...}, Dict2 {Name:b,...}, Dict3 {Name:c,...}.....
Dict6 {Name:f...}
```

This is my code:

```
d = {}     
for key in OriginalDict:
    d['Name'] = key
```

I got a new dictionary but only for the last key.

```
print d 

{Name:f}
```

I guess cos' last value in a dictionary overrides the previous one if the keys are the same

please advise... :)

Comment: the statement `6 new dictionaries having as keys (new keys are same) the value of the original` contradicts your example, in which all the keys are `Name`

Comment: please clarify the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, for example, we put all those dicts in a list, we can use this comprehensions

```
dicts = [{'Name': k} for k in OriginalDict]
```

Let's try it out

```
>>> OriginalDict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}
>>> dicts = [{'Name': k} for k in OriginalDict]
>>> dicts
[{'Name': 'd'}, {'Name': 'c'}, {'Name': 'a'}, {'Name': 'b'}, {'Name': 'e'}, {'Name': 'f'}]
```

The statement `6 new dictionaries having as keys (new keys are same) the value of the original` seems to contradict your example, at least to me.

In such case we can do

```
dicts = [{v: k} for k, v in OriginalDict.items()]
```

Let's try it out:

```
>>> dicts = [{v: k} for k, v in OriginalDict.items()]
>>> dicts
[{4: 'd'}, {3: 'c'}, {1: 'a'}, {2: 'b'}, {5: 'e'}, {6: 'f'}]
```

Comment: in the OriginalDict they are keys plus I guess you still need to loop

Comment: I am sorry, I thought I had understood the question, then I read it again and I got confused. See my final edit.

Comment: brilliant the below works! thanks

dicts = [{'Name': v} for v in OriginalDict]

Comment: if you think my answer solves your problem correctly and better than others', please mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.x:

```
for key in OriginalDict.keys():
     d = {}
     d ['Name'] = key
```

This will give you a new Dictionary for every key of the Original one. Now, you could save them inside a list or inside another dictionary like:

```
 New_Dicts = []
 for key in OriginalDict.keys():
     d = {}
     d ['Name'] = key
     New_Dicts.append(d)
```

Or,

```
 New_Dicts = {}
 for i,key in enumerate(OriginalDict.keys()):
     d = {}
     d ['Name'] = key
     New_Dicts[i] = d
```

Comment: I am in python 2.7. the 2nd one works though. thanks.

Comment: I have another request linked to this one:
I need now add another key in each of the 6 new dictionaries based on the   
values of the of the 6 keys in the original:
target output:

Comment: Can I amend the new dicts?
target output:
[{'Name': 'd', Type: int}, {'Name': 'c', Type: int}, {'Name': 'a', Type: int}, {'Name': 'b', Type: int}, {'Name': 'e', Type: int}, {'Name': 'f', Type: int}]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a function which is a generator, then call that function passing in the dictionary and then yielding your new ones:

```
orig = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}

def make_sub_dictionaries(big_dictionary):
    for key, val in big_dictionary.iteritems():
        yield {'name': key, 'val': val }

# if you want them one by one, call next 

first = make_sub_dictionaries(orig).next()

print first

# if you want all of them 
for d in make_sub_dictionaries(orig):
    print str(d)
    # do whatever stuff you need to do
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is as follows:

```
OriginalDict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}
newDicts = [{'Name':v} for k,v in enumerate(OriginalDict.values())]
```

which will give you

```
>>> newDicts
[{'Name': 1}, {'Name': 3}, {'Name': 2}, {'Name': 5}, {'Name': 4}, {'Name': 6}]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this won't keep the order. You need to use OriginalDict to preserve the order.

```
my_dict={'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}
j=0
for key, value in my_dict.iteritems():
    j +=1
    exec("Dict%s = %s" % (j,{key:value}))
```

Now when you type.

```
>>> print Dict1
    {'a':1}
>>> print Dict2
    {'c':3}
```